# UIButton initWithFrame:CGRectMake not working in Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, xcode9.3

update the xcode to 9.3 and I have problems with the programmable button

in Xcode 8 I have it in the following way and it works well

```
UIButton *btnSettingsButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
[btnSettingsButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnSettingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(setttingsDashboard:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnSettingsButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
UIBarButtonItem *btnSettingsItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnSettingsButton];
```

**screen Xcode 8** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiwSw.png)

the image "settings.png" of the button shows me well with a height of 25 and width of 25.

but when I actulice to xcode 9 does not take the initWithFrame: CGRectMake and it comes out much bigger. "the size of the button image

**screen Xcode 9.3** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYCDn.png)

**How can i fix this?**

Comment: what is settings.png  size

Comment: settings.png  have a size  50 X 50

Comment: try to do it 25x25  because button is stretch to its size

Comment: and there's no way that the button stays with the size I give it? and the image stays with that size of the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `initWithCustomView`, you are making a custom bar button item.

- In iOS 10 and before, this had a fixed size (based, as you rightly observe, on the *frame*).
- But in iOS 11, this behavior completely changes: iOS 11 uses *auto layout* to get the custom bar button item's size.

Therefore, you need to supply internal *auto layout constraints* (e.g. height and width constraints) that dictate the size of the custom view. If you give your button a height constraint of 25 and a width constraint of 25, all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize image to be `25x25`

**or**

just set content mode for Image

```
[[btnSettingsButton imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[btnSettingsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem in adding a bar button item like :-

```
UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(setttingsDashboard:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

solve it by placing

```
[btnSettingsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnSettingsButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
btnSettingsButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, -20);
```